# Unable to start DSE Graph on reset Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am testing DSE Graph (using DSE 5.0.7) a on a single node and managed to corrupt it completely.  As a result I wiped out all the data files with the intention of rebuilding everything from scratch.  On the first restart of Cassandra I forgot to include the -G option but Cassandra came up fine and was viewable from Opscenter, nodetool etc.  I shut this down, and cleared out the data directories and restarted Cassandra again, this time with the -G option.  It starts up and then shuts itself down with the following warning written to the log:

> WARN  [main] 2017-06-08 12:59:03,157  NoSpamLogger.java:97 - Failed to create lease HadoopJT.Graph.  Possible causes include network/C* issues, the lease being disabled, insufficient replication (you created a new DC and didn't ALTER KEYSPACE dse_leases) and the duration (30000) being different (you have to disable/delete/recreate the lease to change the duration).
>   java.io.IOException: No live replicas for lease HadoopJT.Graph in table dse_leases.leases Nodes [/10.28.98.53] are all down/still starting.
>           at com.datastax.bdp.leasemanager.LeasePlugin.getRemoteMonitor(LeasePlugin.java:538) [dse-core-5.0.7.jar:5.0.7]

After this is the error

> ERROR [main] 2017-06-08 12:59:03,182  Configuration.java:2646 - error parsing conf dse-core-default.xml
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.

with a 0 byte dse-core-default.xml being created.  Deleting this and retrying yields the same results so I suspect this is a red herring.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this short of reinstalling everything from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might be fixed by removing a very large java_pidnnnnn.hprof file that was sitting in the bin directory.  Not sure why this fixed the problem, if anyone has any idea?